# mysql transaction not working with innodb tables

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, sql

i write this but transaction not working and i also convert both tables in innodb type can any one guide me whats wrong in my coding or another alternative of transaction.

```
mysql_query("begin;");
  $query1 = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE products ADD COLUMN {$_POST[fields]} VARCHAR(60)");

  $query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fields (cid5,fields,field_title,field_type)
                      VALUE ('$_POST[cid]','$_POST[fields]','$_POST[field_title]','$_POST[field_type]')");                

if (($query1)&&($query2)) {mysql_query("commit;");}
else {mysql_query("rollback;");}

}
```

**i am using mysql 5.1.69-cll**

Comment: make an echo on each query, check the syntax, run it nativly, post the error message. And then always keep in mind: NEVER eat raw $_POST or $_GET variables

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: Why the `asp.net` tag?

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE is a DDL (Data Definition Language) statement; which is not transactional in MySQL innodb engine. INSERT is a DML statement (Data Manipulation Language), which is transactional. Because one statement isn't transactional and one is, the two shouldn't be combined in a transaction.

Quoting from the MySQL manual:

> Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data
>   definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or
>   drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored
>   routines.
>
> You should design your transactions not to include such statements. If
>   you issue a statement early in a transaction that cannot be rolled
>   back, and then another statement later fails, the full effect of the
>   transaction cannot be rolled back in such cases by issuing a ROLLBACK
>   statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cannot-roll-back.html